# how to pack my operations into a function by using expect

Tags: tcl, expect

I have a problem when I want to pack my operations into a function by using epext, the following are what the code looks like, the command ifconfig won't be executed when it be packed into a function, where did I do wrong, how can I pack my operations into a function? Thanks in advance.

```
spawn ssh x.x.x.x

proc do_sth {} {
  send "ifconfig\r" # won't work
  expect "~\]\#" {exit 0}
}

expect {
  "*assword" { send "xxx\r"; exp_continue }
  "~\]\#" { do_sth }
  #"~\]\#" { 
  #  send "ifconfig\r"  # this would works fine
  #  expect "~\]\#" {exit 0}
  #}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try sending the configurations with the `spawn_id`

```
spawn ssh x.x.x.x
#After process creation the process id will be saved in 
#standard expect variable'spawn_id'
#Copying it to variable 'id'
set id $spawn_id
```

Now the variable 'id' is holding the reference to the ssh process. We can very well use the send and expect with the spawn id.

```
#Now we are setting the spawn id to our ssh process to make sure 
#we are sending the commands to right process
#You can pass this variable 'id' as arg in 'do_sth'   
proc do_sth { id } {
    set spawn_id $id
    send "ifconfig\r"
    expect "~\]\#" {exit 0}
}
```

Or the other way around is as follows,

```
 proc do_sth { id } {
    #This way is useful, when u want to send and expect to multiple process 
    #simultaneously.
    send -i $id "ifconfig\r"
    expect -i $id "~\]\#" {exit 0}
}
```

As usual, you can simply call them as below.

```
do_sth $id
```